# Recomended way to keep the state in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: session, sharepoint, state, shopping-cart

What is the recommended way to persist the state in a SharePoint 2013 application?

I need implement a Shopping Cart functionality in SP.

Also, it would be great if you can point me an open source implementation of a Shopping Cart in SP.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you be more specific? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I didn't try anything yet, but I was reading that Sessions are not the recommended way to go, so, I'm wondering what to use instead.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend persisting the data in a database.  You will need to store some sort of identifier on the client (I used a cookie for the web order id along with a hashed & salted value of the order id).  Once you have that bit figured out it is relatively straight forward to read/write back to the database to persist the order info.

Also going this route lets you follow up with the customer should they be logged in or identifiable (Think of the way Best Buy emails you if you leave something in the cart and never order it, marketing folks LOVE that).

Just some food for though, HTH!